# Getting P6083 as model name for nokia lumia 625 using PnpObject Device Container

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing one application and want model name on which my app would be running. I am using WinRT for development. But below code gives me P6083 as Model Name.

```
var pnp = await PnpObject.CreateFromIdAsync(PnpObjectType.DeviceContainer, "{00000000-0000-0000-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}", new[] { "System.Devices.ModelName" });
var deviceName=" + (string)pnp.Properties["System.Devices.ModelName"];
```

Can anyone help on these

Answer (score 0):

Look at the EasClientDeviceInformation type - it is easier to use. But these return internal product names, not marketing names (which can differ by geography / carrier / etc).